# django safe template filter customization

Tags: python, django, django-templates, rich-text-editor

i'm using a rich text editor for users comments reply. but i need to limit html tags which users type in text editor for avoiding xss attacks.

i know that `safe` template filter is best choice.
but as a example i'd  just accept some tags like `<p>,<a>,<h3>` not `img,script,...` . the problem is that `safe` filter accepts all of html tags.

i'm looking for some thing like this:

```
{{user.reply|safe:'<p>,<h3>,<a>'}}
```

which reply is client's richtext html tags.
and `safe` flter just accepts `p,a,h3` tags.

i,m using froala rich text editor and also i know to limit text editor options. but if user try to insert some `<script>` tag it can't undrestand.

how can i customize `safe` filter? or which filter is more appropriate for this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) for this

you can install and use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='includeHtmlTags')
def includeHtmlTags(value, arg):
    include=arg.split(",")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    return_value=''
    for tag in include:
        for i in soup.findAll(tag):
            return_value += i
    return return_value
```

In your template load `{% load includeHtmlTags %}` at top

and use like `{{user.reply|includeHtmlTags:'p,h3,a'}}`

Comment: did'nt try can you please test and see so that we can improve if it affects.